# Error while installing Apache on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, perl

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server I need **Apache 2.4.5 or greater**. I do this:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2
```

But when I run the last command I get:

```
Setting up apache2 (2.4.20-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1) ...
Feature bundle "5.16" is not supported by Perl 5.14.2 at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 14
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 14.
dpkg: error processing apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems I need a newer version of Perl. How do I get that? I can't find a PPA with it.

Comment: try `sudo dpkg -a --configure`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always view the details of a PPA by visiting its page in Launchpad.

The PPA you are using can be found at https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5, and according to its maintainer, the PPA you added does not support Ubuntu 12.04.

```
This PPA contains latest PHP 5.5 packaged for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty).

[...]

If you need other PHP versions use:
  PHP 5.4: ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)
  PHP 5.5: ppa:ondrej/php5 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)
  PHP 5.6: ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)
  PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0: ppa:ondrej/php (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)
```

The PPA from that the same maintainer which is used for 12.04 ([`ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable`](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-oldstable)), does not include apache 2.4 and is no longer supported.

Update (from ondrej): I finally tackled the a2enmod Perl code and the fix for Ubuntu 12.04 was not that hard in the end, so 2.4.20-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2 should contain the fixed code.

Update 2 (from ondrej): I moved all apache2 related packages to `ppa:ondrej/apache2` to avoid duplication.  Unfortunately there's no way how to express this in the PPA dependencies.

Comment: So I will need to update to ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @macurie if updating is an option, I highly recommend it. Besides, Apache 2.4 is the default version in 14.04

Comment: We've been using this PPA for a while and it just broke for us today. Even though the text says it supports 14.04, it is still building binary packages for 12.04, it just won't install. :(

Comment: @DavidBaucum Is there any way to solve this problem without updating? Regarding updating, I have problems with this also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/757759/vmbuilder-and-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: @DavidBaucum You can try building apache2.4 from source on 12.04 if you cannot update. Though unfortunately, I can't help with that as I never tried it.

Comment: I think @Dan has it right. An installation from source code is probably the only way to go.

Comment: @DavidBaucum Given my needs which source should I use?

Comment: @oerdnj The apache2 package seems to be gone from the ppa now.

Comment: @macurie You have to use `ppa:ondrej/apache2` to get apache2_2.4.x packages now.

Answer (score 3):

As I too was having this issue on some Ubuntu 12.04 servers I was maintaining, I decided to create a clone of Ondrej's PPA with the last known working Ubuntu 12.04 packages.

https://launchpad.net/~nickmoline/+archive/ubuntu/php55

Switching to this PPA has allowed me to successfully install Apache and PHP again.

this locks Apache to 2.4.16 instead of the unworkable 2.4.20

Before I did this I contacted Ondrej who let me know that they will eventually fix the problem, but they don't have a timeframe on this, when they do, I'll go ahead and update my PPA and add a note that you can stop using it.

Feel free to use it if it is helpful to you.

Comment: Never mind me, I see @oerdnj updated the above answer to indicate he already resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can find and download the old packages from the build history:

```
wget -A deb -m --no-parent https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5/+build/7886307
wget https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5/+build/7886308/+files/apache2-data_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_all.deb
```

This set of packages are from a previous version that should not depend on Perl 5.16.